# "NSCFArray mutated while being enumerated" error when enumerating a copy 

Tags: python, objective-c, nsarray, enumeration, pyobjc

```
def leopardRemoveWireless(networkName):
  plistPath = '/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist'
  # Sanity checks for the plist
  if os.path.exists(plistPath):
    try:
      pl = NSMutableDictionary.dictionaryWithContentsOfFile_(plistPath)
    except:
      print 'Unable to parse file at path: %s' % plistPath
      sys.exit(1)
  else:
    print 'File does not exist at path: %s' % plistPath
    sys.exit(1)
  # Create a copy of the dictionary due to emuration
  copy = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary_(pl)
  # Iterate through network sets
  for Set in copy['Sets']:
    UserDefinedName = copy['Sets'][Set]['UserDefinedName']
    print 'Processing location: %s' % UserDefinedName

    for enX in copy['Sets'][Set]['Network']['Interface']:
      print 'Processing interface: %s' % enX
      # I think this will always be a single key but this works either way
      for key in copy['Sets'][Set]['Network']['Interface'][enX]:
        print 'Processing Service: %s' % key
        # Try to grab the PreferredNetworks key if any
        try:
          # Iterate through preferred network sets
          index = 0
          for PreferredNetwork in copy['Sets'][Set]['Network']['Interface'][enX][key]['PreferredNetworks']:
            SSID_STR = PreferredNetwork['SSID_STR']
            print 'Processing SSID: %s' % SSID_STR
            # If the preferred network matches our removal SSID
            if SSID_STR == networkName:
              print 'Found SSID %s to remove' % SSID_STR
              # Delete our in ram copy
              print 'Processing Set: %s' % Set
              print 'Processing enX: %s' % enX
              print 'Processing key: %s' % key
              del pl['Sets'][Set]['Network']['Interface'][enX][key]['PreferredNetworks'][index]
            index += 1
        except KeyError:
           print 'Skipping interface without PreferredNetworks'
```

I am editing a fairly complex (dictionary) plist and then writing the changes back to the file after I find a specific key value pair. The issue is that even though I am making a copy of the Property lists dictionary:

```
copy = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithDictionary_(pl)
```

It is giving me the standard "mutated while enumerated" error when I edit the original, just the loop keys as stand ins (notice the lack of quotes).

```
del pl['Sets'][Set]['Network']['Interface'][enX][key]['PreferredNetworks'][index]
```

Is my syntax somehow causing it to try and edit the `pl` dictionary rather then the `copy`? Here is the output:

> ...
>   Processing Set: D5C0A0F4-613A-4121-B6AE-4CBA6E2635FF
>   Processing enX: en1
>   Processing key: AirPort
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/tester/Desktop/wifiutil", line 1164, in 
>       sys.exit(main()) 
>     File "/Users/tester/Desktop/wifiutil", line 1135, in main
>       removeWireless(osVersion,network)
>     File "/Users/tester/Desktop/wifiutil", line 1051, in removeWireless
>       leopardRemoveWireless(network)
>     File "/Users/tester/Desktop/wifiutil", line 528, in leopardRemoveWireless
>       for PreferredNetwork in copy['Sets'][Set]['Network']['Interface'][enX][key]['PreferredNetworks']:
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/_convenience.py", line 431, in enumeratorGenerator
>       yield container_unwrap(anEnumerator.nextObject(), StopIteration)
>   objc.error: NSGenericException - *** Collection  was mutated while being enumerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the issue is the nested nature of the dictionary. `dictionaryWithDictionary_()` doesn't do anything like a deep copy; all it does is create a new `NSDictionary` and copy the pointers for the values (it does copy the keys themselves, since that is the nature of `NSDictionary`).

This means that, although you have a new top-level which you can use for enumeration, the inner dictionaries and arrays are the exact same objects as are in the original.

Your last loop:

```
for PreferredNetwork in copy['Sets'][Set]['Network']['Interface'][enX][key]['PreferredNetworks']:
```

is enumerating one of those inner arrays, which you then try to mutate with a `del` statement:

```
del pl['Sets'][Set]['Network']['Interface'][enX][key]['PreferredNetworks'][index]
```

This wasn't copied; it is the same array object that you are using in the `for`, which causes an exception. You can test this by passing the two expressions to `id()`.

You'll have to either do a full-depth copy of the original dictionary, or (probably better) take a copy of the last level before you enumerate it.

Comment: I tried switching it to   copy = NSMutableDictionary.alloc().initWithDictionary_copyItems_(pl,True)
but still have the same error. Maybe I should make a copy of the NSArray ?

Comment: Yes, that still doesn't do a full-depth copy -- if you look at [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BABECHBH) you'll see that it only copies the first layer; that is something you'll have to code up yourself. Fortunately this is a lot easier in Python than ObjC, but I'd still say the best route is to just copy that last element before you enumerate it.

Comment: copy = NSMutableDictionary.dictionaryWithContentsOfFile_(plistPath) works though its not the best for memory management.